# Sails JS Blueprints allow Update operations on primary key

Tags: node.js, sails.js, crud, waterline

Sails JS creates CRUD for the defined models using blueprints. To do an update you do Model/Update/:id and then pass in the values you want to change. However this allows changing of the primary key. Is there a way to disallow this without defining custom CRUD?

Answer (score 1):

You could add some validation to the model that ensure the new id equals the old id.

As of 2014-11-11 Waterline offers a [beforeUpdate hook](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/f12956b5f5ee0926d332b0ed7d42025fbdef0219/lib/waterline/utils/callbacksRunner.js#L76), in that hook you could ensure that id isn't part of the fields to be updated and if so just delete it from the object.